# What stream does perf use?

Tags: io-redirection, console, output, perf

What stream does the `perf` command use!? I've been trying to capture it with

```
(perf stat -x, -ecache-misses ./a.out>/dev/null) 2> results
```

following https://stackoverflow.com/q/13232889/50305, but to no avail. Why can I not capture the input... it's like letting some fish get away!!

Comment: I don't see a -x option on stat. What version of perf are you using?

Comment: @slm: perf version 3.2.48

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Older versions of perf ~2.6.x

*I'm using perf version: 2.6.35.14-106*.

#### Capture all the output

I don't have the `-x` switch on my Fedora 14 system so I'm not sure if that's your actual problem or not. I'll investigate on a newer Ubuntu 12.10 system later on but this worked for me:

```
$ (perf stat -ecache-misses ls ) > stat.log 2>&1
$
$ more stat.log 
maccheck.txt
sample.txt
stat.log

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

              13209  cache-misses            

        0.018231264  seconds time elapsed
```

#### I only want perf's output

You could try this, the output from `ls` will get redirected to `/dev/null`. The output form `perf` (both STDERR and STDOUT) goes to the file, `stat.log`.

```
$ (perf stat -ecache-misses ls > /dev/null ) > stat.log 2>&1
[saml@grinchy 89576]$ more stat.log 

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

              12949  cache-misses            

        0.022831281  seconds time elapsed
```

### Newer versions of perf 3.x+

*I'm using perf version: 3.5.7*

#### Capturing only perf's output

With the newer versions of `perf` there are dedicated options for controlling where messages get sent. You have the choice of either sending them to a file via the `-o|--output` option. Simply give either of those switches a filename to capture the output.

```
-o file, --output file
    Print the output into the designated file.
```

The alternative is to redirect the output to a alternate file descriptor, `3`, for example. All you need to do is direct this alternate file handle prior to streaming to it.

```
--log-fd
    Log output to fd, instead of stderr. Complementary to --output, and 
    mutually exclusive with it. --append may be used here. Examples: 
       3>results perf stat --log-fd 3  — $cmd
       -or-
       3>>results perf stat --log-fd 3 --append — $cmd
```

So if we wanted to collect the `perf` output for the `ls` command you could use this command:

```
$ 3>results.log perf stat --log-fd 3 ls > /dev/null
$ 
$ more results.log

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

          2.498964 task-clock                #    0.806 CPUs utilized          
                 0 context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               258 page-faults               #    0.103 M/sec                  
           880,752 cycles                    #    0.352 GHz                    
           597,809 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   67.87% frontend cycles idle   
           652,087 stalled-cycles-backend    #   74.04% backend  cycles idle   
         1,261,424 instructions              #    1.43  insns per cycle        
                                             #    0.52  stalled cycles per insn [55.31%]
     <not counted> branches                
     <not counted> branch-misses           

       0.003102139 seconds time elapsed
```

If you use the `--append` version then the contents of multiple commands will be appended to the same log file, `results.log` in our case.

### Installing perf

Installation is pretty trivial:

*Fedora*

```
$ yum install perf
```

*Ubuntu/Debian*

```
$ apt-get install linux-tool-common linux-tools
```

### References

- [System wide profiling](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/profiling/)
- [Tracing on Linux](http://netsplit.com/2011/03/07/tracing-on-linux/)
- [perf: Linux profiling with performance counters](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Counting with perf stat](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat)

Comment: nope, still not redirecting to file. I want to redirect perf's output to file, not my command.

Comment: @DervinThunk - you only want perfs output, correct?

Comment: That is correct. But I think I've found it... there's an --append option in perf

Comment: @DervinThunk - see updates. What version/OS are you on? I don't have that either.

Comment: Linux 3.2.0-52-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 26 16:21:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I'm going crazy. Still not redirecting, even trying your command verbatim.

Comment: @DervinThunk - saw you figured it out. I also found it once I got into my Ubuntu box. Seems the `perf` command has gotten a lot more options since my version of Fedora 8-). I still updated my answer with more details and examples, hopefully it will help others.

Comment: There is no -o option in 'perf version 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64.debug' in CentOS7.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
3>results perf stat -x, -ecache-misses --log-fd 3 --append -- ./a.out
```

as per `man perf-stat`, the `log-fd` flag.